# Overlap an image in real time

Tags: image-processing

I made a real-time face detector with *Mathematica*, and I want to put an image where it detects the face. Here is my code:

```
Dynamic[image = CurrentImage[];
faces = FindFaces[image];
Show[{image, 
      Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Red, Thick}], FaceForm[], Rectangle @@@ faces}]}]]
```

Instead of the rectangle, I want an image to be displayed. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `FaceForm[]` and it is straight forward:

```
coords[{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}}] := {{x1, y1}, {x1, y2}, {x2, 
        y2}, {x2, y1}};

Dynamic[image = CurrentImage[];
 faces = coords[First@FindFaces[image]];
 Column[{
   faces,
   Show[{image, 
     Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Red, Thick}], Texture[(you will have to insert your image HERE)], 
       Polygon[faces, VertexTextureCoordinates -> faces]}]}]
   }]
 ]
```

Comment: it gave me this message Coordinate $CellContext`coords[{{125.5, 13.5}, {235.5, 123.5}}] should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.

Comment: I did but I figured what was wrong it was the image thank you very much